# Commits are not visible in merge request

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge

I've made a merge request for my branch on Git then my colleague made some commits. Commits made by my colleague are visible in merge request section but not mine

I've tried going back to previous commits then committing again but nothing worked.

Comment: you'll need to give more information if you want to get help: if nothing worked, what kind of errors were generated? Did committing work? pushing? what does `git status` give you locally...

Comment: No errors were shown everything worked fine even the commits are visible when I compare my branch with the base branch but they are not visible while making a merge request

Comment: are you sure your commits are pushed? In any case if you don't give more information we cannot possibly guess what is going wrong... try to investigate and show use your results